# C# - Best Way to Match 2 items from a List Without Nested Loops

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, matching

- Say i have a list that hold minitues of film durations called
  **filmDurations** in type of *int*.
- And i have a *int* parameter called **flightDuration** for a duration
  of any given flight in    minitues.

My objective is : 
For any given flightDuration, i want to match 2 film from my filmDurations that their sums exactly finishes 30 minutes from flight.

For example :

- filmDurations = {130,105,125,140,120}
- flightDuration = 280
- My output : (130 120)

I can do it with nested loops. But it is not effective and it is time consuming.

I want to do it more effectively. 
I thinked using Linq but still it is O(n^2).

What is the best effective way?

Edit: I want to clear one thing.

I want to find filmDurations[i] + filmDurations[j] in;

filmDurations[i] + filmDurations[j] == fligtDuration - 30

And say i have very big amont of film durations.

Comment: Haw many films do you have? If the number is not too high O(n²) should be no problem.

Comment: So, you truing to find `i` and `j` in equation `filmDurations[i] + filmDurations[j] ==  flightDuration - 30`?

Comment: Is `filmDurations` sorted ?

Comment: @Fourat no it is not sorted.

Comment: "But it is not effective and it is time consuming." **Possible**, but not **neccssarily** a big problem. Did you **measure** if you *have a problem*? Or did you just *asume* so?

Comment: @AleksAndreev yes, exactly. I want to find i and j

Comment: @MrSmith42 say you are a company like netlflix and you need to give your flight customers exactly 2 film. So you have very big amount of film

Comment: Do you need all fitting combinations or just one?

Comment: For this question, i want just one. I just need the best way

Comment: I think maybe it's possible to find all combination in O(n) if you use dictionary.

Comment: @LeisenChang i will test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Leisen Chang said you can put all items into dictionary. After doing that rewrite your equation

```
filmDurations[i] + filmDurations[j] == fligtDuration - 30
```

as

```
filmDurations[i] == (fligtDuration - 30 - filmDurations[j])
```

Now for each item in `filmDurations` search for `(fligtDuration - 30 - filmDurations[j])` in dictionary. And if such item found you have a solution.

Next code implement this concept

```
public class IndicesSearch
{
    private readonly List<int> filmDurations;
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> valuesAndIndices;

    public IndicesSearch(List<int> filmDurations)
    {
        this.filmDurations = filmDurations;

        // preprocessing O(n)
        valuesAndIndices = filmDurations
            .Select((v, i) => new {value = v, index = i})
            .ToDictionary(k => k.value, v => v.index);
    }

    public (int, int) FindIndices(
        int flightDuration,
        int diff = 30)
    {
        // search, also O(n)
        for (var i = 0; i < filmDurations.Count; ++i)
        {
            var filmDuration = filmDurations[i];
            var toFind = flightDuration - filmDuration  - diff;
            if (valuesAndIndices.TryGetValue(toFind, out var j))
                return (i, j);
        }

        // no solution found
        return (-1, -1); // or throw exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sort all durations (remove duplicates) (**O(n log n)**) and than iterate through them (until the length flight-duration -30). Search for the corresponding length of the second film (**O(log n)**).

This way you get all duration-pairs in **O(n log n)**.

---

You can also use a *HashMap* (duration -> Films) to find matching pairs.

This way you can avoid sorting and binary search. Iterate through all durations and look up in the map if there are entries with duration = (flight-duration -30).

Filling the map needs **O(n)** lookup **O(1)** and you need to iterate all durations.

-> Over all complexity **O(n)** but you loose the possibility to find 'nearly matching pairs which would be easy to implement using the sorted list approach described above)

Comment: It seems decent, but i'm not sure if there is better way or not.

Comment: This will not increase speed in in terms of o-notation, but you can improve the search when you consider the length of the shortest film and the resulting boundary for the longest possible film.